# ggplot: several boxplots in one won't work

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing concentrations of 7 phthalate metabolites (MEHP HMEHP OMEHP MEP MBZP MIBP MNBP) as well as one column containing the population (mothers, fathers, children). I want to create one plot with the phthalate metabolite concentrations on the x axis and inside the plot three boxplots per metabolite showing the concentrations for mothers, fathers and children.
The data looks like this:

```
  MEHP HMEHP OMEHP MEP MBZP MIBP MNBP population
1   27    60    34  28   23   46   39    mothers
2    1   2.1   2.1 8.5  1.3   14  8.6    mothers
3  2.8    11   5.3  16  1.8   17   21    mothers
4  3.9    63    35 120   14   93  120    mothers
5  4.6    19   9.2 9.8  3.2   25   22    mothers
6  1.2   6.2   4.9  34  1.8   17  9.2    mothers
```

I first melted the data and then I tried to plot it

```
df.m <- melt(data2, id.var = "population")
df.m

  population variable value
1    mothers     MEHP    27
2    mothers     MEHP     1
3    mothers     MEHP   2.8
4    mothers     MEHP   3.9
5    mothers     MEHP   4.6
6    mothers     MEHP   1.2

ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x=variable, y=log(value) +  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=population))
```

I am getting the error

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x=variable, y=log(value) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=population))   
ggplot"
```

And I don't know why it's not working. Thanks!

UPDATE
adding )) after y=value worked. 
Unfortunately, it then gave me the error

```
> ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x=variable, y=log(value))) +  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=population))
Error in Math.factor(value) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors

> str(df.m)
'data.frame':   2499 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ population: Factor w/ 3 levels "children","fathers",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3  3 ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 7 levels "MEHP","HMEHP",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : Factor w/ 317 levels "#N/A","0.25",..: 58 27 53 68 77 29 44     118 38 115 .
```

How do I solve this?

UPDATE

```
data2 <- read.csv2("190123_phthalates_population.csv", header=T,  stringsAsFactors=F, sep=";")
head(data2)
str(data2)
> str(data2)
'data.frame':   357 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ MEHP      : chr  "27" "1" "2.8" "3.9" ...
 $ HMEHP     : chr  "60" "2.1" "11" "63" ...
 $ OMEHP     : chr  "34" "2.1" "5.3" "35" ...
 $ MEP       : chr  "28" "8.5" "16" "120" ...
 $ MBZP      : chr  "23" "1.3" "1.8" "14" ...
 $ MIBP      : chr  "46" "14" "17" "93" ...
 $ MNBP      : chr  "39" "8.6" "21" "120" ...
 $ population: chr  "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" ...

df.m <- melt(data2, id.var = "population")
head(df.m)
  population variable value
1    mothers     MEHP    27
2    mothers     MEHP     1
3    mothers     MEHP   2.8
4    mothers     MEHP   3.9
5    mothers     MEHP   4.6
6    mothers     MEHP   1.2
str(df.m)
'data.frame':   2499 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ population: chr  "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 7 levels "MEHP","HMEHP",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : Factor w/ 317 levels "#N/A","0.25",..: 58 27 53 68 77 29 44     118 38 115 ...

as.numeric(as.character(df.m$value))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
na.omit(df.m)
> str(df.m)
'data.frame':   2499 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ population: chr  "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" "mothers" ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 7 levels "MEHP","HMEHP",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : Factor w/ 317 levels "#N/A","0.25",..: 58 27 53 68 77 29 44 118 38 115 ...
ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x=variable, y=(value)) +   geom_boxplot(aes(fill=population)))

Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`.
```

It's still not working

UPDATE it worked by changing the values in the excel file from general to numeric, save as csv and load again.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of closing parenthesis. Your first `aes(` never closes. Your `ggplot(` never closes. Add `))` after `log(value)`. Suggesting to close as typo.

Comment: You're missing a `)` and call aes once.

Comment: Try this: `ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x=variable, y=log(value),fill=population)) +  geom_boxplot()` You should use RStudio and set it to a syntax highlighting theme.

Comment: Convert to numeric. all values from `1:(ncol(df)-1)`.

Comment: Your variable `value` is of type `factor`. You need to convert it to numeric with `as.numeric(as.character())`

Comment: You have to save the change to the column. `df.m$value <- as.numeric(as.character(df.m$value))`. (Just like `x + 1` doesn't change `x`. If you want to update `x` to be one higher, you do `x <- x + 1`.) Don't worry about omitting the `NA`s, ggplot will do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks! That works too